# use SwiftMailer in Command - Symfon 4.1

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I created a simple command witch takes url and look if website is up if not send email to me, but the problem is i don`t know how to add SwiftMailer to Command execute.

```
    <?php

namespace App\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Style\SymfonyStyle;
use App\Entity\Products;
use App\Entity\Settings;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;

class CheckwebsitesCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected static $defaultName = 'checkwebsites';

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('app:checkwebsites')
            ->setDescription('Add a short description for your command')

        ;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output, \Swift_Mailer $mailer)
    {
```

if i add a:

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output, \Swift_Mailer $mailer)
{
```

then i have a error:

```
 Warning: Declaration of App\Command\CheckwebsitesCommand::execute(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface $input, Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface $output, $id)
  should be compatible with Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command::execute(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface $input, Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface $ou
  tput)
```

i can`t understand this "Commands" thing, why i can`y just attach bundles witch, as i want ? I wanna use Commands to setup crons.

******EDIT

```
   foreach($websites as $website) {
                       $www = $website->getJson();
                       $online = url_test($www['website']['www']);
                       if(!$online) {
                         $message = (new \Swift_Message('Nie działa strona '.$www['website']['www'].' !'))
                         ->setFrom(''.$emailform.'')
                         ->setTo(''.$emailform.'')
                         ->setBody(
                           $this->templating->renderView(
                             'emails/websitenoworking.html.twig',
                             array(
                               'www' => $website['website']['www'],
                             )
                           ),
                           'text/html'
                         );
                         $mailer->send($message);
                       }
                     }
```

Comment: The action injection stuff that you see with controllers only work with controllers.  For commands you should inject the mailer service into the constructor.

Comment: this https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/injection_types.html?

Comment: The injection type link merely list the types of injection supported.  None of them are applicable to your execute example above.  It is somewhat confusing that the link uses MailerInterface in the examples but Symfony does not have a "out of the box" MailerInterface.  This link is perhaps a better example: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#handling-multiple-services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to follow up a bit on my injection comment, given that you are using S4.1 you should probably avoid using the ContainerAwareCommand as well.  Using the container as a service locator is so last year.  Strict dependency injection is the recommended approach.

```
namespace App\Command;

use Twig\Environment;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class MailerCommand extends Command
{
    private $entityManager;
    private $mailer;
    private $twig;

    public function __construct(
        EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, 
        \Swift_Mailer $mailer,
        Environment $twig
    )
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->twig = $twig;
    }
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('app:checkwebsites')
            ->setDescription('Add a short description for your command')
        ;
    }
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        echo "Hello there\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: ok works, but if i try in swiftmailer renderView() function got  `Attempted to call an undefined method named "renderView" of class "Swift_Mailer".`

Comment: i don`t know how to inject templating twig in construct

Comment: And that is because Swift_Mailer does not have a renderView method.  Swift Mailer does not care how you render stuff.  renderView comes from Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerTrait.  Might take a peek at the code there to see what you need to inject to get it working.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to inject twig.  But before you ask more, pause and see if you find the answer on your own.  And as a rule, updating a question with an existing valid answer is considered to be a tiny bit rude.

Comment: ok i understand, but from where you know what to use: i.e. use Twig\Environment; i know it that i have to inject twig but ...from where to know that i have to exaclly use this sentence use Twig\Environment;

Comment: A search like: "symfony inject twig" will do the trick.  It does take time and effort to understand services and how to use them effectively.  Mostly a question of becoming confident in searching the docs.  And the debug:container command can also be very handy: "bin/console debug:container | grep Twig" once you understand the output.

Answer (score 2):

Full working:

```
<?php

namespace App\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Style\SymfonyStyle;
use App\Entity\Products;
use App\Entity\Settings;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Twig\Environment;

class CheckwebsitesCommand extends Command
{
      private $entityManager;
      private $mailer;
      private $twig;

      public function __construct(
          EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
          \Swift_Mailer $mailer,
          Environment $twig
      )
      {
          parent::__construct();
          $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
          $this->mailer = $mailer;
          $this->twig = $twig;
        }
    protected static $defaultName = 'checkwebsites';

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('app:checkwebsites')
            ->setDescription('Add a short description for your command')

        ;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $io = new SymfonyStyle($input, $output);



                    $websites = $this->entityManager
                     ->getRepository(Products::class)
                     ->findBy([
                       'type' => 1,
                     ]);

                     $settings = $this->entityManager
                     ->getRepository(Settings::class)
                     ->findOneBy([
                       'id' => 1,
                     ]);
                     $json = $settings->getJson();
                     foreach($json as $prop) {
                       foreach($prop as $key => $value) {
                         $$key = $value;
                       }
                     }

                      //funkcja sprawdzająca czy strona działa
                      function url_test( $url ) {
                              $timeout = 10;
                              $ch = curl_init();
                              curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
                              curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
                              curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout );
                              $http_respond = curl_exec($ch);
                              $http_respond = trim( strip_tags( $http_respond ) );
                              $http_code = curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
                              if ( ( $http_code == "200" ) || ( $http_code == "302" ) ) {
                                return true;
                              } else {
                                // return $http_code;, possible too
                                return false;
                              }
                              curl_close( $ch );
                            }




                     foreach($websites as $website) {
                       $www = $website->getJson();
                       $url = $www['website']['www'];
                       $online = url_test($url);
                       if(!$online) {
                         $message = (new \Swift_Message('Nie działa strona '.$www['website']['www'].' !'))
                         ->setFrom(''.$emailform.'')
                         ->setTo(''.$emailform.'')
                         ->setBody(
                           $this->twig->render(
                             'emails/websitenoworking.html.twig',
                             array(
                               'www' => $url,
                               'firma' => $www,

                             )
                           ),
                           'text/html'
                         );
                         $mailer->send($message);
                       }
                     }


        $io->success('Sprawdzono wszystkie strony.');
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to change renderView to render aswell

Comment: and $mailer->send to $this->mailer->send of course @Cerad thank you to explain mi this Command stuff, now i crash it :D